# Speed up hard link creation in unix

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix, hardlink

I have a work to make new hardlinks for 60000+ (30.3 GB) files with different names. The problem is, the directories, the old file names, and the new hard link names is stored in a CSV file. Right now, I am writing a script to do it automatically (parsing the csv, looping through records, and making the link). Below is the sneak peek from the script

```
while read col1 col2 col3 col4
do
        if [ $counter -ne 0 ];
        then
                if [ ! -f "$col2$col3.jpg" ]; then
                        # File not found, need to track how much is not found
                        echo "$col2$col3.jpg"
                        notfound=$(expr $notfound + 1)
                else
                        if [ $(expr $hash / 10) -eq 1 ]; then
                                hash=$(expr $hash - 10)
                        fi

                        ln "$col2$col3.jpg" ./testtemp-1/$hash/$col4.jpg
                        hash=$(expr $hash + 1)
                fi
        else
                counter=$(expr $counter + 1)
        fi
done < test.csv
```

It takes around 15 minutes to complete this thing. May I know if there is any idea to shorten the time? It is quite time sensitive task which will be done in the production (right now it is on testing).

PS: I need the hashing so it can't be deleted. Not found is also required. $col2 -> directory name, $col3 -> file name, $col4 -> new hard link name

Comment: Are you hellbent on using Bash for this? The bottleneck is probably in the disk I/O but I certainly see some things there which would probably be a lot faster (and more elegant!) in Python or some other modern scripting language.

Comment: If you are using Bash, a subshell to add one to a number is quite inefficient and expensive. Bash has built-in integer arithmetic; you want to replace `value=$(expr $value + 1)` with `((value++))`

Comment: What does `hash` contain and where is it defined?

Comment: Get your script checked here: [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: You could use `${hash%?}` to drop the final digit without actually using division at all.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers. Actually the reason why I prefer to use bash is because this machine was quite old (centos 6.5) and I would prefer not to change the environment, like by adding python or stuff. Hash basically used to distribute the files evenly. Before, the directories from csv contained different number of files (some are just 4 gb, some has 40 gb). Please let me know if there is a better hashing function that I can use

Comment: If you could explain how `hash` is supposed to be calculcated, I suspect there may be a simple two- or three-liner to replace this whole thing.

Comment: just 0 - 9, simple folder division

Comment: This is crying out for **Perl**, where maths and strings are built in and `ln` is a library call not a whole new process...

Comment: Your script might be much more readable if the first line were `while read _ dir file link` ...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to cut down the time to a very reasonable one (2 mins) by changing the expr and skipping the first line check logic. Thanks for the comments :)